# Joomla Administration menu auto-disable in the internal sections

Tags: menu, administrator

When I go to a section in the administration, for instance Article -> Create, the administration menu turns disabled. It seems the reason is to prevent sudden click on the menus and turning away from some data-sensitive pages, such as creating an article whose sudden click can lead to loss of half an hour work. Now, my first question is that, Am I true? Is such behavior standard?

Second, is there any method to turn such behavior off?

Here is a snapshot of the menu when it is disabled.

[image: Administration menu being disabled in certain sections of the site.]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the reason behind disabling the top menu on edit views. You'll get some people that are performing different tasks in the back-end on different tabs and accidentally navigate to a different page using the top menu, on the wrong tab.

I don't know how other CMS's approach something like this, but I'd say yes, it is standard practice.

The code that does this is:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('hidemainmenu', true);
```

Which is located in a component's `view.html.php`, which cannot be overridden, so instead, I'd suggest creating a [Template Override](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) for the component's view (`default.php`) and adding the following:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('hidemainmenu', false);
```

I haven't tested this, but am pretty sure it will work.

Comment: I'll check it, thanks. Would set the answer if it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried if it is possible to solve that with a system plugin and it worked :-)

You can download the plugin here:
https://github.com/fruppel/plg_enableadminmenu/releases

Remember to publish the plugin after installation.